# no idea where tkinter label is being defined in class

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, tkinter, super

I found this code for a label class for a tkinter popup I was making. I didn't understand how the label appeared, but I just went on with it. However later I found that I needed to refer to the created label in order to bind to it. I have no idea what line is the actual place the label is being created, so when I was trying to assign the label to a variable, I didn't know where. Can someone please explain what is happening in this code and how I can call back to the label I just created inside the class?

I figured out the label is being created somewhere where `super()` is being used and has something to do with the `Label` parameter being passed directly to the class. However after researching what `super().__init__()` did I figured it just allows classes to use parameters from other classes, so I'm still confused on how it works when its referring to itself. I also am confused on where the parameters passed directly into the class go (rather that being in the `__init__`)

I tried assigning the `super()` to a variable, or just using `Label` as a variable, or removing the `self`. at the beginning.

I made a mini version of the class to see what was going on but to no success. Here is the code:

```
from tkinter import *


class Label(Label):
    def __init__(self, root, text, row, col, tag):
        self.text = text
        self.row = row
        self.column = col
        self.root = root
        self.tag = tag
        super().__init__(root)
        self['text'] = self.text
        self.grid(row=self.row, column=self.column)
        # self.label.bind("<Configure>", self.move) # this is the line of code im trying to get to work, but    cant because i dont know where the label is being created. it doesnt work           
    def move(self):
        print('moving')

root = Tk()
display = Toplevel()
output = 0
ans = Label(display, output, 0, 0, 'yes')
root.mainloop()
```

Sorry if this is a bad question and or it is answered somewhere else this is my first question on here and I'm pretty sure theres another easy solution but I just really want to understand what is happening here.

Comment: The newly created class is assigned to the name `Label` **after** its complete definition was executed. Therefore at `class Label(Label)` the second `Label` refers to `tkinter.Label` yet until the class is fully defined. This means the new `Label` class is derived from `tkinter.Label`. Of course this is very bad style.

Comment: Don't use `Toplevel`.

     #display = Toplevel()
    output = 0
    ans = Label(root, output, 0, 0, 'yes')
    root.mainloop()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have no idea what line is the actual place the label is being created

It is this line:

```
ans = Label(display, output, 0, 0, 'yes')
```

That is because `Label` is a superclass of tkinter's `Label` class, so any instance of this class is a label. Within the class the actual label object is referred to with `self` and is created when this line executes:

```
super().__init__(root)
```

You don't need to assign the result of `super().__init__(root)` to a variable. That is handled automatically by python.

> However later I found that I needed to refer to the created label in order to bind to it.

You should bind to `self`:

```
self.bind("<Configure>", self.move)
```

---

<sup>1</sup> You should not be naming a custom class the same as an imported class. That will make the code more confusing. I recommend that you rename your `Label` class to something else, such as `CustomLabel`.